# Computing rolling median absolute deviation

Tags: stata

I am trying to calculate the rolling median absolute deviation (MAD) of a variable `x` for each group `id`, using `20` observations.

Example data:

```
clear
set obs 100

generate id = _n
expand 100

generate x = rnormal()
bysort id: generate time = _n
```

I have already managed to compute the median for the rolling observations using the *community-contributed* command `rangestat`:

```
rangestat (median)  x, by(id) interval(time -20 0)  // this works
```

I then tried to use the *community-contributed* command `tsegen` with `egen`'s function `mad()` to compute the rolling median absolute deviation:

```
xtset id time
tsegen mad_x = mad(L(0/20).x) // this does not work
```

However, this last command results in the following error:

```
x__000001__000002__000003__000004__000005__000006__000007__000008__000009__00000A__00000B__00000C__00000D__00000E__00000F__00000G__00
> 000H__00000I__00000J__00000K invalid name
r(198);
```

How can I pass the "use 20 observations" requirement to `mad()`?

Cross-posted on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1521527-how-to-compute-rolling-median-absolute-deviation).

Answer (score 0):

**My preferred solution has been posted on Statalist [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1521527-how-to-compute-rolling-median-absolute-deviation).**

Another solution is to add lagged variables and compute the MAD manually:

```
xtset id time

rangestat (median) x (count) x, by(id) interval(time -20 -1)

/* Add lagged values */

forvalues i = 1 / 20 {
    generate double L`i'x = abs(L`i'.x - x_median)
}

/* Compute median of those /*

egen mad = rowmedian(L*x)
```